# Insert/Edit Image not working properly in Firefox 14-15 for tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tinymce

I have Firefox 15 and windows 7. I right click on an image, then select insert/edit image. The first time it will load fine, then click cancel.

Follow the above again and the window will freeze - this happens on a hosted site/server, in local server I am getting a `500 - Internal server error.`

Other then Firefox every browser is working fine could anyone tell me why this is happeing?

I have latest version (3.5.6).

Comment: can you create an online example of this problem - eigther on an own server or using tinymce fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added tinymce in page with parameter/query string, so I think its not properly attached into system. I have remove that parameter/query string and its work perfect.